# Is ssl required for authentication system?

Tags: php, security, encryption, ssl

i'm developing a website with videos. i do not have any transactions in my site. i have a login system.

Do you think i require ssl for the login system? i've even integrated facebook, so mostly users would login with their facebook account.

Is there any alternative for ssl for websites like mine?

Comment: I can't think of a MitM proof login without SSL with current browsers.

Comment: Require? No. Should have? Absolutely yes, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything you pass over the Internet without using SSL/TLS (or an equivalent system to encrypt/protect the confidentiality of the information you are passing) must be assumed to be completely compromised and visible to anyone. In your case, that would include usernames, passwords, and session tokens, which could allow an attacker to learn your UN/PW combinations, so they could impersonate users for the long term, and session tokens so they could act as a logged in user.

Do you need to protect this? Absolutely a risk decision. What is the sensitive level of your data? What would be the consequences if this compromise happened? What would your users think if their usernames and passwords were to be made available to the world? As users tend to reuse passwords among websites, then there would be some damage to your site's reputation (and your reputation) should this happen.

The same thing can happen with your Facebook-based login. This uses OAuth, which is just a bearer token sent from the client to your server. If this is sent outside of an SSL/TLS tunnel, it has to be assumed to be compromised and, based on how bearer tokens work, anyone who can see the token and reuse it and act as the user.

Basically, SSL/TLS is cheap, both in terms of the cost of a certificate from a respected and trusted CA and server power/latency. If you have a user base of any significant size, then it most likely a very easy decision to use SSL/TLS.

Comment: You can buy a SSL from a widely used root for as little as $10 year. No reason to skip one unless you're talking about a blog.

Answer (score 1):

I would seriously consider using a 3rd party OpenID or OAuth provider as an authentication system.  There are many considerations for handling a login.  Often users are put at risk by custom login systems that use weak hash functions to store the password.  A good example is the [Gawker leak which used DES for password storage](http://iqsecur.blogspot.com/2012/01/analysis-of-gawker-leak.html).  Pretty terrifying stuff,  especially when you think that this can be avoided entirely.

Obviously you need SSL to transmit a username and password over the network.  But really the user is authenticated to your application using a cookie value or session token.  This is the **real method of authentication**  and why [OWASP a9](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A9-Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection) requires that this value is never spilled over an insecure channel.

If your website is worth anything at all,  then use SSL to protect your user's sessions.  If your website is useless and no one cares about having an account,  then why build it?

Answer (score 0):

Many people use the same logins on different sites, so to prevent eavesdropping, it is recommendable to use ssl.

If it is the price you are worried about and you do not do any financial transactions on your site, you can try to get a free certificate: https://www.startssl.com/?app=1

Comment: if its free, then what is the difference between the paid one and the free one?

Comment: @Lalith Mohan Only the domain and email address are verified, not your identity or the identity of your business.

Comment: @LalithMohan The only difference is that free is cheaper than paid. There is no reason to use anything but the cheapest certificate. (EAV certs have slight advantages, but aren't necessary for you)

Comment: The username and password isn't the only problem.  The session id is what is actually used to maintain an authenticated client. OWASP a9